# prolog unification resolution

Tags: prolog, resolution, exponentiation, unification

Why does this work:

```
   power(_,0,1) :- !.
   power(X,Y,Z) :-
      Y1 is Y - 1,
      power(X,Y1,Z1),
      Z is X * Z1.
```

And this gives a stack overflow exception?

```
power(_,0,1) :- !.
power(X,Y,Z) :-
  power(X,Y - 1,Z1),
  Z is X * Z1.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because arithmetic operations are only performed on clauses through the `is` operator. In your first example, Y1 is bound to the result of calculating Y - 1. In the later, the system attempts to prove the clause power(X, Y - 1, Z1), which unifies with power(X', Y', Z') binding X' = X, Y' = Y - 1, Z' = Z. This then recurses again, so Y'' = Y - 1 - 1, etc for infinity, never actually performing the calculation.

Prolog is primarily just unification of terms - calculation, in the "common" sense, has to be asked for explicitly.

Comment: doesn't Y - Y' - Y'' - Y''' ... - 1 eventually equal to zero falling into the base case and terminating the recursion?

Comment: Nope, in Prolog `Y - 1` when `Y = 1` is still `Y - 1` while it is not bound :)

Comment: Indeed - it's just a syntactic form. The infix notation is just that - notation. It's equivalant to -(Y, -(Y', -(Y'', Y'''))). Which is going to just going to expand forever, until you associate some semantic meaning with -. This is what "-" does.

Comment: Silly SOF. I added a correction that got lost - "This is what `is' does"

Answer (score 1):

Both definitions do not work properly.

Consider

```
?- pow(1, 1, 2).
```

which loops for both definitions because the second clause can be applied regardless of the second argument. The cut in the first clause cannot undo this. The second clause needs a goal `Y > 0` before the recursive goal. Using `(is)/2` is still a good idea to get actual solutions.

The best (for beginners) is to start with [successor-arithmetics](/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics) or [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) and to avoid [prolog-cut](/questions/tagged/prolog-cut) altogether.

See e.g.: [Prolog predicate - infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740271/prolog-predicate-infinite-loop/9741582#9741582)