# Prolog getting inifinite loop when asking for another solution

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop, exponentiation, successor-arithmetics

I am using SWI Prolog, the following code is used in my homework(the code is not the homework but needed to write the methods the course requires):

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :-
    nat(X).

plus(0,N,N) :- 
    nat(N).
plus(s(M),N,s(Z)) :-
    plus(M,N,Z).

times(0,N,0) :-
    nat(N).
times(s(M),N,Z) :-
    times(M,N,W),
    plus(W,N,Z).

exp(s(M),0,0) :-
    nat(M).
exp(0,s(M),s(0)) :-
    nat(M).
exp(s(N),X,Z) :-
    exp(N,X,Y),
    times(X,Y,Z).
```

`exp(a,b,c)` means `c=b^a`.

It is copied directly from the book: "The Art of Prolog: Advanced Programming Techniques".

When I run the following query:

```
exp(s(s(0)),L,s(s(s(s(0))))).
```

I get an answer:

```
L = s(s(0))
```

But when I ask for another answer by entering ;

```
L = s(s(0)) ;
```

I get an infinite loop(ending in an out of stack error), I was expecting to get false.

What is the problem in the code? is there a code that does the same(with the same representation of natural numbers) but behaves the way I described? and if so, a few pointers or suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the order of `exp/3`. Means `exp(a,b,c)` `c=b^a`?

Comment: yes, I added it to the question.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740271/prolog-predicate-infinite-loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal that it runs in to an infinite loop for the given program: if you call `exp/3`, With the second element being uninstantiated, it starts branching over all possible values for `L`. In other words, if you query:

```
exp(s(s(0)),L,s(s(s(s(0))))).
```

It acts as:

> I instantiate `L` to `s(0)`, is `s(0)` (thus 1) correct?
>   No! I instantiate `L` to `s(s(0))` is 2 correct?
>   Yes return `2`. Hold on, the user asks for more answers....
>   Is `3` correct? No
>   Is `4` correct? No
>   Is ... correct? (you get the idea)

Each time you make an attempt, the stack is risen one level deeper (because it requires one more level to construct `s(X)` over `X`...

You could try to use another way: there is a logical upperbound: the result (third argument), so you could first instantiate the second argument as the third and test and then decrement the second argument until you find the correct result.

Comment: hank you for the quick answer, I understand why it goes into an infinite loop now, but I'm a bit confused about your suggestion, for simplicity sakes lets consider the example I gave above, do you mean that I should look at L as s(s(s(s(0)))) = 4, and then I should test 4^2 =? 4, no -> 3^2 =? 4, no->  2^2 =? 4, yes. -> ; -> 2^1 =? 4, no, 2^0 =? 4, no -> false. ?